# How to adjust the view port to get a website to display on mobile?

Tags: mobile, meta-tags

I have been working on an older website, and I was hoping someone could assist me with getting this website to display on mobile.

https://www.technobox.com

I realize this website needs to have a mobile optimized version, but I need to put a band-aid on this issue for the time being. Right now the website appears zoomed in, and I need help finding the correct code to have it display the full page.

This is probably an easy fix for the viewport META tag, but I just want to make sure I am using the correct techniques.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should hire a web designer who can make your website responsive. Till that time, use following viewport for mobile devices.

```
You should include the following <meta> viewport element in all your web pages:

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```